# GDM not starting and I can't open TTY

Tags: boot, gnome, login, tty, gdm

I can't login to my ubuntu environment. It will get stuck on the purple screen and I can't even open TTY by using ctr+alt+F1-F5

I've read this: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162087#162087)

and a lot more forum posts but the main problem is that I can't open TTY, I've tried open it also by using `no splash` and `nomodeset` but no luck.
Somehow I should restart my GDM to get my ubumtu up and run again.

All suggestions or advices are highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I would also get rid of 'quiet splash' on the 'linux' line (so you get more messages), and maybe add a '1' (or 'single) so you can login and start to explore (was a change made, what was change... in logs)   [I've not used 'no splash'..]

Comment: @guiverc Hi, I removed quiet splash and added single but the results were the same. The purple screen comes in and only key combination I can use is CTRL+ALT+DEL for restart the system and I'm back in GRUB 2 Menu.